# How to run ">" UNIX command by child_process in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, child-process

I'm trying to run a command on a Linux based OS and save the output on a file. This is what I do when i'm using terminal:

```
wpa_passphrase SSID sample_password > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I want to run this command on my NodsJS app but it doesn't work properly:

```js
const wpa_passphrase = spawnSync('wpa_passphrase', [`"${ssid}"`, `"${password}"`, '>', paths.wpaConfig]);
```

The problem is, it doesn't run the `>` command in order to save the output on my specified path.
how should I run this command by **spawnSync**?

Comment: try setting `shell` option to `true`

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options

Comment: @AkhilThayyil it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `shell` option to `true`

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options